# How ansible callbacks are configured

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have scoured the ansible documentation as well as a few books, google and the source code, but for the life of me I cannot find the answer to this simple question:

How does one change the configuration items that affect the beahavior of ansible callbacks?

-E.g: the mail callback appears, looking at the code, to be able to be configured to send mail to a configurable email address through a configurable SMTP host. How/where/when should these be specified?

TIA

**Edit:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, OK, if the mail callback (and the base class for callbacks) are anything to go by, there appears to be NO standard configuration mechanism for callbacks. Mail gets SMTPHOST from an environment variable if it's there, and to: appears to be nailed to root.

Comment: You ever figure this out? This sucks, we're running into the same issue.

Comment: @luckytaxi: nope, I gave up on callbacks. They appear to be a rather half-baked feature, not really flexible enough for general usage. At least, that's the way I understand them.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the email address to your own in the mail.py file

```
    if sender is None:
        sender='<root>'
    if to is None:
        to='<root>'
```

You can change the root to your own email address, and the each host output will be sent as an email.

Also please make sure you have whitelist the plugins in ansible.cfg file.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the callbacks plugins directory and then also whitelist it (I am assuming that you are using Ansible 2.0+) inside the `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
callback_plugins = ./plugins/callback_plugins
callback_whitelist = name_of_your_plugin_here
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yeah I got that far,What's missing, tho' is; assune I do not want mail notiffies ti root (but to buzz@my.place) how do I tell the mail callback? The code says I cant.

Comment: Nothing changed for me!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you really need to look at the code for now to get the full documentation. Looks like currently the only way to configure it is by setting the [`SMTPHOST` environment variable](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/mail.py#L22). The slack plugin allows configuration via either environment variables or by adding settings to the [`[callback_slack]` section of ansible.cfg](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/slack.py#L27)